# Is it possible to detect sensor support on a Firefox OS device?

Tags: sensors, firefox-os

I'm planning to add support for various sensors like light sensor, motion sensor, orientation sensor and proximity sensor to my Firefox OS app. But while trying to understand how those device APIs work, I cannot seem to find an API call to detect whether a specific sensor is supported by the underlying device hardware. Is it possible to do that in any ways from an app?

Comment: Easy, try to use a sensor, if it doesn't work it's probably not there. Chances are that the api won't be available if the hardware isn't present.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm afraid that's not a great solution, since even in the simulator all sensors seem to be there (to check it I use e.g. "var availMotion = 'ondevicemotion' in window") and possible to have a listener registered. Same goes for real devices where even the non-supported sensors can be registered. Of course the registered event function is never called, but I would prefer to check if a sensor hardware is there before even registering a listener for it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have proximity sensor API here < https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Proximity_Events >
You can find boilerplate app here which uses proximity API and other couple of API's here< https://github.com/robnyman/Firefox-OS-Boilerplate-App >

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't answer my question. I know how to handle sensors, my app already does that just fine. What I'm looking for is a mechanism to detect e.g. if the accelerator sensor is present in the device where my app is running on. I can't seem to find an API call to do that. And even when a particular sensor is unsupported by the underlying hardware, I can register the listener just fine. Which is wrong IMHO. In my book it shouldn't be possible to register a listener to a non-existing (not implemented) sensor.